# Using onClickListener to take me to another XML file

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I quite new/unfamiliar with Java so forgive me if my terminology is a bit off.

To summarize, I have buttons in my XML file which I'd like to take me to another page (like a hyperlink would in HTML, etc.) But when entering this, an error appears with the two `setActivity()` parts of the code:

> The method `setActivity()` is undefined for the type `new View.OnClickListener(){}`

Here is the code for the class:

```
public class HomePage extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        Button button1 = (Button)setActivity().findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(setActivity(), LinkHome.class);
                startActivity(i);               
            }
        });       
    }
    ...
```

Can anyone give me any advice to get around with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It  might help to you.

```
Intent i = new Intent(HomePage.this, LinkHome.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Cians I used your example which helped me remove the second setActivity() error.

Comment: Sorry, i had problems editing the comment....
Cians I used your example which helped me remove the second setActivity() error which is useful. Since then I added more buttons: [link] (http://pastebin.com/vcPNX2wX) 

So now I'd stil having the setActivity error: `the method setActivity() is undefined for the type HomePage`. 
If I create a method it makes

`private Activity setActivity() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }` 

at botom of code but the errors disappear. Does that mean it is fixed or will I get other errors down the line?

Comment: My friend used an setActivity() when using an onClickListener for his code. Is there an easier way to use the 5 buttons as links to other pages within my app?